# how to get name of foreign key constraint when record can't be deleted within a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a stored procedure to merge and dedup records.   it executes updates dozens of tables and also deletes rows from other tables when a merge is completed.

When the script fails it is always because there's foreign key reference I've forgotten to integrate into the script  (large schema; hundreds of tables).

Previously, MySQL 5.7 would return the name of the specific foreign key via the MESSAGE_TEXT variable.  MySQL 8 doesn't appear to do this.

How can I get the specific foreign key that is causing the record from being deleted?

Comment: Does this help? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/get-diagnostics.html